# Is Shiny Xerneas possible with game restarts?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I am in the room with the Xerneas tree, and I keep reopening the game to find a shiny. Is it possible to find a shiny that way? If so, than will it show Xerneas shiny in the cutscene?

Answer (score 0):

**No, this is not possible.** Starting with Generation 5, some Pokemon are programmed such that you cannot encounter their shiny variant in the wild.

Taken [directly from Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny):

> **Unobtainable Shiny Pokémon**
>   In all generations since Shiny Pokémon debuted, there are a few species that cannot be legitimately obtained Shiny. This can be caused by being impossible to obtain except through a direct event distribution, or by being programmed so that they cannot be Shiny in the wild (Generation V onward).
>
> **Generation II**
>   - Mew[note 1]
>   **Generation III and on**
>   - Celebi
>   **Generation IV and on**
>   - Arceus
>   - Spiky-eared Pichu*
>   **Generation V and on**
>   - Victini
>   - Reshiram
>   - Zekrom
>   - Keldeo
>   - Meloetta
>   **Generation VI**
>   - Xerneas
>   - Yveltal
>   - Zygarde
>   - Diancie